# JAVA: Convert IEnvelope to Shapefile

Tags: java, gis, shapefile

I am currently attempting to convert an IEnvelope to a Shapefile and am at a stand still. I am at a point where I have retrieved the IEnvelope from the Shapefile but am not sure how to go about converting to a Shapefile object. The relevant code I have is listed below:

```
  private final ResultsMenuAction createLayerAction = new ResultsMenuAction("uiCreateLayer") {
    protected void doActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button hit!");
        try {
            ImmutableSet<FeatureWrapper> features = getFeatures();
            Iterator itr = features.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                FeatureWrapper wrapper = (FeatureWrapper) itr.next();
                IGeometry geom = wrapper.getOriginalShape();
                IEnvelope envelope = geom.getEnvelope();
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (ArcEngineException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AutomationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

};
```

Comment: Generally you have to create new IFeatures and save those to the shape file. However I can't be more specific since you don't show what your `getFeatures()` method does. I assume you are using arcGIS engine, but I suggest you also post version info. You also need to post more info on the feature types you read and the ones you want to save.